# Finding the volume of pyramid.

Tags: geometry

*Question:*

A triangular pyramid is cut of from the corner of a cube. Given that **AB** $=$ **AC** $=$ **AD** $=6$cm, find the volume of the pyramid.

[image]

*Solution:*

Since the angles BAC, DAB, CAD are all right angles, BD=BC=CD=$6\sqrt{2}$.
Since all the sides are equal, all angles of base triangle BCD are $60^.$.

Height of triangle BCD $= \sin{60}\times 6\sqrt2 = 3\sqrt6$

Base area $= \frac{1}{2} \times 3\sqrt6 \times 6\sqrt2 = 18\sqrt3$

But how to find the height of the pyramid?

Comment: I have a solution using the vector cross product but will aim to provide a solve with elementary methods. Also, $AB \neq 6\sqrt{2}$ as, by hypothesis, it has length $6.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson Sorry, I typed it wrong.It was supposed to be BD.

Comment: If the goal is to find the volume of the pyramid, why not treat $\triangle ABC$ as the pyramid base and $AD$ as the pyramid height?

Comment: @peterwhy yes, I didn’t think of that. Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h$ be the height of the named pyramid. Then you have: $\dfrac{1}{3}S_{\triangle BCD}\cdot h = \dfrac{1}{6}AB\cdot AC\cdot AD\implies \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot 18\sqrt{3}\cdot h = \dfrac{1}{6}\cdot 6^3$. Can you finish it here ?

Comment: Why does it equal to $1/6 AB \cdot AC \cdot AD$?

Comment: Because the volume $V$ of the pyramid can be calculated using this method too. Viewed the height being $AD = 6$, and the base the triangle $\triangle ABC$  which is a right triangle whose area equals to $\dfrac{1}{2}AB\cdot AC \implies V = \dfrac{1}{3}Sh = \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}AB\cdot AC \cdot AD = \dfrac{1}{6} AB\cdot AC\cdot AD$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let us call $E$ the projection of $A$ on the plane determined by the triangle $\triangle BCD$.

Since the triangle $\triangle BCD$ is equilateral, the following relation holds:

\begin{align*}
|AE|^{2} + |CE|^{2} = |CA|^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow |AE|^{2} + \left(\frac{2}{3}\frac{6\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2} = 6^{2}\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |AE|^{2} + 12 = 36\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |AE| = 2\sqrt{6}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the base triangle is an equilateral triangle, the foot of perpendicular of the height will lie exactly on the centroid of the base triangle.

I mean, if $AH$ is the height of this pyramid, where $H$ is on $BCD$, then $H$ is the centroid of the triangle $BCD$. From the property of centroid of triangle, we have $DH$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the height of the base triangle, that is, it equals to $3\sqrt{6}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=2\sqrt{6}.$ And look at the triangle $AHD$, this is a right triangle so we have
$$AH^2+DH^2=AD^2$$
Plug in your data and solve for $AH.$